# Embedded HTML in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'd like to know if this is possible at all.  What I want to do is to create a wrapper VisualForce page which simply takes a URL as a parameter, and renders it.  I have tried this, but it renders the HTML text and not the page.  Any suggestions?

Thx,
Hamayoun

Controller:

```
public class wrapper1 {

public String output {set;get;}

public wrapper1 () {

    String url1 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('url1') ;
    PageReference pr = new PageReference (url1);
    output = pr.getContent().toString();

}

}
```

VisualForce:

```
<apex:page controller="wrapper1">
<apex:outputPanel>
  {!output}
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Warning:** What your proposing to do is a significant security issue. I'd highly suggest that you severely restrict where the page will pull HTML in from or look for a different option.

See also: [HTML Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML_Injection)

---

Try switching to an [apex:outputText](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm) and setting the escape attribute to false. This will stop Salesforce from HTML escaping the content.